# C# Mysql populate list<T>

Tags: c#, mysql, class, bind

I'm trying to populate list from mysql with the below code. My model looks like this https://pastebin.com/iQEVV42C

My goal is to populate the lists then take the sub lists and put them into the root (tickets) how can I do this?

```
 public static async Task<IEnumerable<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Root>> Tickets(int ticketId = 0, int clientId = 0)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Root> tickets = new List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Root>();
            List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Incidents> ticketIncidents = new List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Incidents>();
            List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Files> ticketFiles = new List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Files>();
            List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Comments> ticketComments = new List<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Comments>();
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Variables.conString))
            {
                await con.OpenAsync();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM tickets;" +
                               "SELECT * FROM ticket_incidents;" +
                               "SELECT * FROM ticket_files;" +
                               "SELECT * FROM ticket_comments;";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = (MySqlDataReader)await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        // tickets
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            tickets.Add(new Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Root()
                            {
                                header_text = reader.GetString("name"),
                                description = reader.GetString("description"),
                                status = reader.GetString("status"),
                                source = reader.GetString("source"),
                                owner = reader.GetString("owner"),
                                temp = reader.GetString("temp"),
                                priority = reader.GetString("priority"),
                                category = reader.GetString("category"),
                                creation_team = reader.GetString("creation_team"),
                                last_updated = reader.GetDateTime("last_updated"),
                                creation_date = reader.GetDateTime("creation_date"),
                                client_id = reader.GetInt32("client_id"),
                                ticket_id = reader.GetInt32("ticket_id"),
                                unique_id = reader.GetInt32("unique_id")
                            });
                        }
                        await reader.NextResultAsync();

                        // ticket_incidents
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            ticketIncidents.Add(new Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Incidents()
                            {
                                header_text = reader.GetString("header_text"),
                                description = reader.GetString("description"),
                                type = reader.GetString("type"),
                                creation_team = reader.GetString("creation_team"),
                                created_by = reader.GetString("created_by"),
                                notify_team = reader.GetInt32("notify_team"),
                                notification_seen = reader.GetInt32("notification_seen"),
                                is_pinned = reader.GetInt32("is_pinned"),
                                creation_date = reader.GetDateTime("creation_date"),
                                incident_id = reader.GetInt32("incident_id"),
                                ticket_id = reader.GetInt32("ticket_id"),
                                unique_id = reader.GetInt32("unique_id")
                            });
                        }
                        await reader.NextResultAsync();

                        // ticket_files
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                           // Not filled yet
                        }
                        await reader.NextResultAsync();

                        // ticket_comments
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                           // Not filled yet
                        }
                        await reader.NextResultAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tickets.First().owner);
            return tickets;
        }
```

My issue is how I can fill the sub classes (ticket_incidents, ticket_files, ticket_comments) and then put it into the root class?

Comment: For any given `ticket_incident` (or any other "sub class"), how do you identify which `ticket` it belongs to?

Comment: @David, when populating it should of course do it in a respectively order. Plus we have the ids to match

Comment: *"it should of course do it in a respectively order"* - The `SELECT` queries you're showing have no `ORDER BY` clauses, so you may want to ease back on the "of course" there.  The data is going to be returned in a non-guaranteed order unless you specify one.  *"we have the ids to match"* - If you have that information, use it.  When you want to add any given `ticket_incident` to any given `ticket`, find the `ticket` which has that id and add it.

Comment: Please, please, please, please, please use some kind of ORM. I have a project in production from back in the day when I didn't know any better and mapped objects manually, like you're doing. It literally ruins my day/week/month when something breaks or they request an enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you might save a lot of time by using an ORM to query your database; it will turn a set of related tables into an object graph.

Secondly, if you're going to avoid a full ORM and read the data directly via ADO.NET, I would recommend [Dapper](https://dapperlib.github.io/Dapper/), which will remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Here's how the main body of your method would look with Dapper:

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM tickets;" +
    "SELECT * FROM ticket_incidents;" +
    "SELECT * FROM ticket_files;" +
    "SELECT * FROM ticket_comments;";
using var gridReader = await con.QueryMultipleAsync(query);

// NOTE: Assumes database columns are named exactly the same as the object properties
var tickets = (await gridReader.ReadAsync<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Root>()).ToList();
var ticketIncidents = (await gridReader.ReadAsync<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Incidents>()).ToList();
var ticketFiles = (await gridReader.ReadAsync<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Files>()).ToList();
var ticketComments = (await gridReader.ReadAsync<Models.Zelkon.Tickets.Comments>()).ToList();
```

Thirdly, if you're using `async` with MySQL, uninstall Oracle's MySQL Connector/NET (i.e., `MySql.Data`) and use [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) instead. It's a [longstanding bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111) in Connector/NET that async operations actually operate completely synchronously.

Finally, to link your objects together, iterate over each collection and attach the object to the right `Root` object. One way to do this would be to put your `Root` objects in a `Dictionary` keyed on their ID:

```cs
var ticketsById = tickets.ToDictionary(x => x.ticket_id, x => x);

foreach (var incident in ticketIncidents)
    ticketsById[incident.ticket_id].incidents.Add(incident);
foreach (var file in ticketFiles)
    ticketsById[file.ticket_id].files.Add(file);
foreach (var comment in ticketComments)
    ticketsById[comment.ticket_id].comments.Add(comment);
```

This assumes that the `Root` object has an `incidents` property (`files`, `comments`) that's initialized to an empty `List<Incidents>` (`List<Files>`, `List<Comments>`). You will need to write that code if it doesn't exist.

Again, any decent ORM (Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc.) will provide all of this code for you "out of the box", so you wouldn't even have to write this method at all.